# how to move data from one level to another

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, levels

This is my data

```
levels(ab$age)    
# [1] "18-25"        "26-30"       "31-35"    "36-40"    "41-45"    "46-50"    "51-55"    "56-60"   
# [9] "61-65"    "66-70"    "71-75"    "Above 46"
```

I want to move level "41-75" into "Above 46" How do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "move X into Y?". Do you want to append the data from X into Y, then remove X?

Comment: `levels(ab$age)[levels(ab$age) %in% c("46-50", "51-55", "56-60", "61-65", "66-70", "71-75", "Above 46")] <- "Above 46"`

Answer (score 2):

Using the `forcats` package from the Tidyverse

```
library(forcats)

ab <- data.frame(age = factor(levels = c("18-25", "26-30", "31-35", "36-40", "41-45", "46-50", "51-55", "56-60", "61-65", "66-70", "71-75", "Above 46")))

ab$age <- fct_collapse(ab$age, 
            "Above 46" = c("46-50", "51-55", "56-60", "61-65", "66-70", "71-75", "Above 46"))
```